# Given a kernel of a linear transformation and image being a subset, find all associated matrices of $f$ with respect to canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\ f:\mathbb R^3  \to \mathbb R^3$ be a linear transformation such that:

$\ker (f) = \operatorname{span}  \{ (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) \}$ and $\operatorname{Im} (f) \subseteq  \operatorname{span} \{ (0,1,0),(0,0,1) \}.$

Find all associated matrices of $f$ with respect to canonical basis.

Can anybody help me with this?

What I tried is basically useless, the only think I concluded that the matrix should have rank $1$ since dimension of kernel space is $2$, this is an old exam question with which I have a problem and have been breaking my head for already more than half an hour...

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you provide a generic matrix with kernel as above?

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Comment: The part with the image is also confusing me

Comment: I assume there should be a span in front of the two element set after the image?

Comment: Yes a generic matrix would be any such that first and second columns are zero, at least i think so, and yes there should be a span, i forgot to put the sign

Comment: @VukStajkic Yep, because multiplying the first two standard basis vectors to a matrix will give you the first two rows. Since you want them both in your kernel, the first two columns need to be $0$ vectors.

Comment: Now what about the third column vector (i.e. the image of $(0, 0, 1)$). What can it be? (Also note that it cannot be $(0, 0, 0)$, as this would mean the kernel was not equal to the span of the given two vectors, but in fact be all of $\mathbb{R}^3)

Comment: So basically the matrix (or all possible matrices ) is one with first 2 column vectors 0 and third one being practically any vector(except 0 vector), since it would be the image. Did i understand it right @TheoBendit ?

Comment: Pretty much, but remember, you do have to respect the restrictions on the image space. For example, you couldn't have a column $(1, 0, 0)$!

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks a lot, btw it is my first time on this forum, so do i have to do anything to close the topic? Did not have time to read all the rules, exam is tomorow :(

Comment: If there was a particularly helpful answer (not comment!), then choose it as best answer (after the minimum time has elapsed). Since there were no answers, there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why not write up your comments as an answer? Once you got into the extended discussion, that seems like it would’ve been more appropriate, anyway.

Comment: @amd It's a good idea. I just preferred the more conversational style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm writing up the answer in the comments.)

Note the following fact about $3 \times 3$ matrices (which generalises to higher dimensions):
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{c}a_{11} \\ a_{21} \\ a_{31}\end{array}\right) \\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{c}a_{12} \\ a_{22} \\ a_{32}\end{array}\right) \\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{c}a_{13} \\ a_{23} \\ a_{33}\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
Put simply, multiplying a matrix by the $k$th (column) vector in the standard basis, returns the $k$th column in the matrix.

Fix some $f$ satisfying the conditions in the question, and let $M$ be its standard matrix. Since we know $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) \in \operatorname{ker} f$, we know that
$$M\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right) = M\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right).$$
So, using the above fact, the first two columns of $M$ must contain only zeros. We similarly know the third column of $M$ must be non-zero, otherwise,
$$(0, 0, 1) \in \operatorname{ker} f = \operatorname{span}\lbrace (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \rbrace = \mathbb{R}^3.$$
We are further restricted in what the third column can contain by the restriction on the image of $f$. Since it must be contained in $\operatorname{span}\lbrace (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \rbrace$, we must have
$$M\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ a \\ b\end{array}\right)$$
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, which forms the third column. Thus, $M$ must take the form,
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & b\end{array}\right)$$
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, with $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$. It is not difficult to verify that every such matrix satisfies the conditions, so we have our characterisation.